# BTCPay Server intergration using Greenfield API / php

Tags: php, btcpay-server

So I am trying to integrate btcpayserver into my site. I am fairly new to php so bare with me but I have everything working until after the invoice is created. Whenever user clicks to pay with bitcoin, it successfully creates new invoice but doesn't redirect to the checkout link afterwards.

I should mention i am using the following to help with integration process https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-greenfield-php

Here is my create_invoice.php

```
session_start();

// Include autoload file.
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Import Invoice client class.
use BTCPayServer\Client\Invoice;
use BTCPayServer\Client\InvoiceCheckoutOptions;
use BTCPayServer\Util\PreciseNumber;

// Fill in with your BTCPay Server data.
$apiKey = 'aaaaaaaaaa';
$host = 'https://aa.demo.btcpayserver.org/';
$storeId = 'aaaaaa';
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$currency = 'USD';
$orderId = $_SESSION['name']."#" . mt_rand(0, 1000);
$buyerEmail = $_SESSION['name'];

try {
    $client = new Invoice($host, $apiKey);
    var_dump(
        $client->createInvoice(
            $storeId,
            $currency,
            PreciseNumber::parseString($amount),
            $orderId,
            $buyerEmail
        )
    );
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Whenever the form is submitted the following is shown (i replaced the sensitive information)

```
object(BTCPayServer\Result\Invoice)#6 (1) 
{ 
  ["data":"BTCPayServer\Result\AbstractResult":private] => array(16) 
  { 
    ["id"]=> string(22) "aaaaaaaaaaa" 
    ["storeId"]=> string(44) "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" 
    ["amount"]=> string(4) "18.0" 
    ["checkoutLink"]=> string(62) "https://demo.aa.btcpayserver.org/i/aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" 
    ["status"]=> string(3) "New" 
    ["additionalStatus"]=> string(4) "None" 
    ["monitoringExpiration"]=> int(1669087659) 
    ["expirationTime"]=> int(1669080459) 
    ["createdTime"]=> int(1669078659) 
    ["availableStatusesForManualMarking"]=> array(2) 
    { 
      [0]=> string(7) "Settled" 
      [1]=> string(7) "Invalid" 
    } 
    ["archived"]=> bool(false) 
    ["type"]=> string(8) "Standard" 
    ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
    ["metadata"]=> array(1) 
    { 
      ["orderId"]=> string(4) "#501" 
    } 
    ["checkout"]=> array(10) { 
      ["speedPolicy"]=> string(9) "HighSpeed" 
      ["paymentMethods"]=> array(1) 
      { 
        [0]=> string(3) "BTC" 
      } 
      ["defaultPaymentMethod"]=> NULL 
      ["expirationMinutes"]=> int(30) 
      ["monitoringMinutes"]=> int(120) 
      ["paymentTolerance"]=> float(0) 
      ["requiresRefundEmail"]=> NULL 
      ["defaultLanguage"]=> NULL 
    } 
    ["receipt"]=> array(3) 
    { 
      ["enabled"]=> NULL 
      ["showQR"]=> NULL 
      ["showPayments"]=> NULL 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Now my issue is I need to redirect to "checkoutLink" after invoice is created.

UPDATE*

Following code displays error "Error: Cannot access offset of type string on string"

```
if ($response->getStatus() === 200) {
        $data1 = $response->getBody();
        $link1 = $data1["checkoutLink"];
        echo $link1;
        
    } else {
        throw $this->getExceptionByStatusCode($method, $url, $response);
    }
```

Comment: And what is preventing you from doing that, exactly?

Comment: Im not sure to be honest. Im newer to php development and am not sure how to redirect the user to "checkoutLink" after invoice is created.

Comment: Have you tried googling "how to do a redirect in php", or similar?

Comment: Or are you asking how to get the link from the invoice data so you can use it? It's unclear where you're stuck

Comment: If you're going to show code, please [edit] the question rather than showing it in the comments, it would be much easier to read there. Thanks

Comment: I just updated it. Thanks @ADyson

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but how is that code related to the first bit? It's unclear. I was expecting to see some attempt to extract data from the output of `$client->createInvoice`, as per your first snippet.

Comment: @ADyson
That was from the github file I was trying to use (linked above) to integrate it. How would i go about extracting from output $client->createInvoice ? sorry for the confusion I am trying best I can to explain

Comment: _"but it displays all arrays in getBody()"_ - that method doesn't take any parameters - https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-greenfield-php/blob/a9fe84fc9ed810ae13163930367069fa3585aa82/src/Http/Response.php#L30

Comment: Well the data in the var_dump is in a private property, so you can't get it directly. But as per https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-greenfield-php/blob/a9fe84fc9ed810ae13163930367069fa3585aa82/src/Result/AbstractResult.php you can call getData() to get that object, and then after that you should be able to get the link property easily.

Comment: So probably something like `$client = new Invoice($host, $apiKey); $result = $client->createInvoice($storeId, $currency, PreciseNumber::parseString($amount), $orderId, $buyerEmail); $data = $result->getData(); $link = $data["checkoutLink"];`

Comment: @ADyson Whenever i take out the var_dump it returns a blank page,  create_invoice.php

Comment: Error: Call to a member function getData() on null

Comment: That's weird, you must be using some different data or something. Because `$result` should contain the same data that is shown when you do the `var_dump`

Comment: @ADyson
I figured out the previous error but now it is giving me this error "Error: Cannot access offset of type string on string" I have tried to google but still am having issues

Comment: It sounds like $data1 is a string then. Did you try echoing that? If you're getting a raw body data then you'll need to json_decode it (assuming it contains JSON) before you can use it like a variable and extract individual data items from it.

Answer (score 0):

$client = new Invoice($host, $apiKey);

```
$response = $client->createInvoice(
        $storeId,
        $currency,
        PreciseNumber::parseString($amount),
        $orderId,
        $buyerEmail
    );
```

return redirect($response->getCheckoutLink());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delay, but I hope you have already resolved your issue. Nonetheless, I believe the answer will not only help you but also prove beneficial to others facing a similar problem. The modification focuses on redirecting to the payment page after creating the invoice:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Include autoload file.
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; // Make sure this path is right

// Import Invoice client class.
use BTCPayServer\Client\Invoice;
use BTCPayServer\Util\PreciseNumber;

// Fill in with your BTCPay Server data.
$apiKey = 'aaaaaaaaaa';
$host = 'https://aa.demo.btcpayserver.org'; // The BtcPay Server host
$storeId = 'aaaaaa';
$amount = (float) strip_tags($_POST['amount']);
$currency = 'USD';
$orderId = strip_tags($_SESSION['name'])."#" . mt_rand(0, 1000);
$buyerEmail = strip_tags($_SESSION['email']); // The email is not required but make sure it is well formatted

try {
    $client = new Invoice($host, $apiKey);
    
    $invoice = $client->createInvoice(
        $storeId,
        $currency,
        PreciseNumber::parseString($amount),
        $orderId,
        $buyerEmail
    );

    // Save the data you need to in your db
    // Now redirect the user to the payment url
    header('Location: ' . $invoice->getCheckoutLink());
    exit(); // Make sure to exit after redirecting to prevent further execution.

} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // Handle errors
    var_dump($e);
    die();
}
```

Please do make sure to properly sanitize users' data.